# Legend for moderator tag includes escape code

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags-page

[image: Moderator Tag Legend]

As seen above, the tooltip for the moderator tag legend includes an escape code. Yikes! This behavior is exhibited on every meta site. The offending HTML code is shown below.

```
<a class="post-tag moderator-tag" title="this is a moderator tag; it can only be added to a question by a &amp;#9830; moderator">moderator-only-tag</a>
```

It seems that the reason for this is because the ampersand inside the escape code is *escaped*. How does this even happen?

Comment: [The great escape artist has done it again!](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=amp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be fixed now... Bow before the might of the diamond!

[image]